# Layout and Toast not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, visibility

My `MainActivity` layout consists of 4 embedded `LinearLayout`s, all declared `Visibility:GONE` in the XML. 
The first layout contains just a `TextView`. I set this layout to `VISIBLE`, and then try to display a Toast in it. But neither the `Toast` nor the `TextView` are displayed--just a blank screen.

This same hiding/unhiding technique works in other areas in the activity, but I can't see why it doesn't here.

For `Context` for the `Toast`, I've tried `this`, `MainActivity.this`, and `getApplicationContext()`. Nothing works. (The program works, it just doesn't display the TextView or the Toast)

[code]

```
@BindView(R.id.layout_configuration) LinearLayout linearLayoutConfiguration;
@BindView(R.id.layout_appupdater) LinearLayout linearLayoutAppUpdater; //Added to handle app-updating clause
@BindView(R.id.layout_user) RelativeLayout linearLayoutUser;
@BindView(R.id.layout_capture) LinearLayout linearCapture;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // contains the above 4 layouts, all initialized to GONE visibility
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

        init(); // unrelated to display
    }
```

...

```
if (versionMismatch) {
    setDisplayAppUpdating();
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to update app...");

    //(doesn't print) if we've detected a newer version in the cloud, get it.
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Updating app...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    apkDownloadInteractor = new DownloadApkInteractor (
            ThreadExecutor.getInstance(),
            MainThread.getInstance(),
            Patient.getInstance());

            apkDownloadInteractor.execute();
```

...

```
protected void setDisplayAppUpdating() {
    linearLayoutConfiguration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linearLayoutUser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linearCapture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linearLayoutAppUpdater.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: You must call show() on your toast object.

Toast.makeText().show();

Comment: Add your onCreate method and show where you call setDisplayAppUpdating

Comment: Is the log message getting printed?

Comment: Yes, log prints